# Convert exe to dll programaically

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, exe

I have a program compiled as exe and the programs needs to "convert" itself to a DLL, adding some exported functions. It contains both `WinMain` and `DllMain` functions.
I believe this shouldn't be hard, as this would mean only changing the PE header.
 What's the best way to do it?
Note: Compiling it as DLL and EXE separately is **not** an option.

Comment: Why you have to convert at all? I think you can use `LoadLibrary` with EXE files as soon as they have exported functions.

Comment: @Vitaliy No you can't because the entry point is the wrong form.

Comment: Have your EXE export a [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx) in addition to its regular entry point. Keep in mind, that this has to be the **true** entry point (usually inside the CRT implementation). Now you can hack your PE header to point at the DllMain entry point, and update the optional header field specifying the desired *DllCharacteristics*. Too much hackery for my taste; I'd simply recompile/relink the code to produce a standard DLL.

Comment: Simple approach is to create a DLL that does the work and a thin host executable that is linked to the DLL and calls a function exported by the DLL passing the command line. Then you don't need any hackery at all.

Comment: Another approach is similar to what SysInternals does with a lot of their tools: embed a driver within the .EXE. Instead of a driver embed the DLL. The DLL will largely be redundant with the EXE, but if you don't care about the size of the EXE that won't be a problem. This approach only requires you to distribute one file vs thin EXE/DLL approach requiring two